# Preventing javascript callback from being called on parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, callback, userscripts

I'm working on a userscript which is supposed to be cross-browser compatible which might explain why I'm not doing things the normal way. The script displays a floating div named box which is a jQuery object. The click function looks like this:

```
box.click(function(event) {
    set_visible(false);
});
```

The set_visible function just does a `box.fadeOut(500);`

Inside the parent div I create a menu not using jQuery but plain old javaScript using an array of functions like so (I tried rewriting this function using jQuery but had some issues getting the array functions to work):

```
function doGMMenu() {
    if( !GM_falsifiedMenuCom.length ) { return; }
    var mdiv = document.createElement('div');
    for( var i = 0; GM_falsifiedMenuCom[i]; i++) {
        var bing;
        mdiv.appendChild(bing = document.createElement('a'));
        bing.setAttribute('href','#');
        bing.onclick = new Function('GM_falsifiedMenuCom['+i+'][1](arguments[0]); return false;');
        bing.appendChild(document.createTextNode(GM_falsifiedMenuCom[i][0]));
        if (i+1<GM_falsifiedMenuCom.length)
            mdiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\u00A0\u00A0|\u00A0\u00A0'));
    }
    status.contents().append(mdiv);
}
```

Here's an example of the first array function which displays an options menu:

```
 function() { DisplaySlideMenu(true); }
```

My problem is that when I click on the link, the options menu displays, but the parent divs box.click function is also called which hides it when I don't want to. When the anchor .onclick function is added you can see that the last entry is `return false;` but that doesn't prevent the .click event from propagating up to the parent div. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: You probably need to call `e.stopPropagation()` in the link click handler to keep the click from propagating up to parent objects.

Comment: Thanks! I did a little reading and was able to do it by adding `var e = arguments[0]; e.stopPropagation();` to the bing.onlick function and that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
box.click(function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.stopPropagation();
    set_visible(false);
});
```